# d:DesignHeight and d:DesignWidth not working in XAML Preview of JetBrains Rider

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, jetbrains-ide, rider

I want to set the size for UserControl to design my app. But XAML Preview probably ignores the `d:DesingHeight` and `d:DesingWidth` properties. I can put the `Height` and `Width` properties but is uncomfortable because I will need removing them before running the app.

My XAML code:

```
<UserControl x:Class="CIevlev.ClinicApp.DesktopClient.ControlDoctorService"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:CIevlev.ClinicApp.DesktopClient"
         xmlns:viewModel="clr-namespace:SIevlev.ClinicApp.Interfaces.ViewModel;assembly=SIevlev.ClinicApp.Interfaces"
         mc:Ignorable="d"
         d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800">
    <Grid>

    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

"`d:`" works in Visual Studio. I want to work in Visual Studio :(

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: I ended up seting  MinHeight="42", MinWidth="180"
        Height="{Binding Win_Height, Mode=TwoWay}"
        Width="{Binding Win_Width, Mode=TwoWay}"
to kind of get around this